# Div not obeying 'top' or 'height' styles

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwuy9Lqd/)

I have a `.panel` div that I have created, with some contents in it. I want it to be centered both vertically and horizontally. Horizontal cenetering I have accomplished using `margin:auto;`, but I cant seem to get the vertical centering to work.

As per [this](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/) tutorial, which I have used successfully many times in the past, I have styled my `.panel` with

```
.panel {
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

The position is set to relative, and it is transformed upwards by 50% of it's size, but the top stays at 0%, and thus, the panel is half offscreen. As well, the panel's height is set to 95%, but it is not obeying that either. This is not as important—in the end I want the height to be auto—but I noticed it happening, and figured it might be caused by the same issue that's preventing the top from being set properly. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: create a div before this with relative positioning, and the actual panel position it in an absolute way with the actual css you have right now, so it can work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you are using percentage based units. If you want the element centered *relative* to the window, then the `body` needs to have a height *larger* than its contents (at the moment, the `height` of the `body` element is defined based on the `.panel` element).

In this case, you could just give it a height of the viewport:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/j4jt0twx/)

```
body {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

---

You could also absolutely position the element instead.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fg84363t/)

```
.panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

---

Alternatively, another way to center the element horizontally/vertically would be to add `top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;`, then since a `height`/`width` are given, `margin: auto` will effectively center the element horizontally/vertically.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qd49n75b/)

```
.panel {
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0; right: 0;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
}
```

---

But since the `width`/`height` are specified using percentage based units, you could actually use just center the element using `top: 2.5%`/`left: 2.5%`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/91sg1vvw/)

```
.panel {
    position: absolute;
    width: 95%;
    height: 95%;
    left: 2.5%;
    top: 2.5%;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Not sure why `position:relative` was not working in this case, but absolute positioning seems to! The one thing I would add: while absolute positioning has no centered it vertically, it is no longer cenetered horizontally. To fix this, I have applied that same principle to the left position (left: 50%;, transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

Answer (score 1):

The parent elements have the same height as the panel, which seems to be why it's not working. You can make the panel absolutely positioned, or you can add a height to the parent elements.

[Updated Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xwuy9Lqd/2/)

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
```